# Golang: no required module provides package

Tags: go

I created a new folder with main.go and with following code:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()
    r.GET("/ping", func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "message": "pong",
        })
    })
    r.Run() // listen and serve on 0.0.0.0:8080 (for windows "localhost:8080")
}
```

I run `go mod init gin` and `go mod tidy`.

go.mod and go.sum are created and they are looking fine.

I run `go run main.go` and get this output

```
main.go:6:2: no required module provides package github.com/gin-gonic/gin; to add it:
        go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

`go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin` doesn't solve the issue

It seems like main.go doesn't use go.mod from current directory. I tried setting GO111MODULE="auto" and GO111MODULE="on" without success.

my go env:

```
GO111MODULE="auto"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/xxx/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/xxx/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOEXPERIMENT=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/home/xxx/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/xxx/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.18.3"
GCCGO="gccgo"
GOAMD64="v1"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/home/xxx/files/Programming/go-playground/gin/go.mod"
GOWORK="/home/xxx/files/Programming/go-playground/go.work"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/tmp/go-build3669122409=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches"
```

## SOLVED:

my code example was inside a go workspace and I forgot to add it to the workspace with `go work use`

Comment: Do not use `go run` with filenames, nothing in the official docs suggests to do this. That however is not the actual problem here, there is something you haven't shown us, because your example would still work as presented.

Comment: Guessing here, but `go mod init gin` could be a name that conflicts with `github.com/gin-gonic/gin`. Try  something like `go mod init github.com/your-account/gin`.

Comment: @JimB I tried `go build ` and getting the message `directory . outside modules listed in go.work or their selected dependencies`. Setting GOWORK=off and trying again hasn't worked.

Comment: @DmitryHarnitski I changed the package name to something else without success

Comment: Ok, the problem was my original code was inside a Go workspace and I haven't added it to the workspace with `go work use'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to start http service with following steps

**Directory structure**

```
./Playground/
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
└── main.go
```

Step.1 module init

```
go mod init gin 
go mod tidy
```

Step.2 Add gin dependency

```
go get github.com/gin-gonic/gin
```

Step.3 Create main.go, with code given in question

Step.4 Run

```
go run ./main.go
```

Comment: i followed your steps and it worked. I haven't expected that as the steps are basically the same as in my post but this works strangely. Later this day I'll figure out what the problem is. Thanks

Comment: Ok, the problem was my original code was inside a Go workspace and I haven't added it to the workspace with `go work use'`